# ASP.NET CORE how to send items from input to database and see it on same page

Tags: asp.net-core

I have problem

My application need to work that user write some task and then it shows his task with other tasks on same page where is input. Problem is that I do not understand how to put it that way that user can write his task, then it send on database and then it shows on same page.

```html
@model ICollection<WebApplication1.Models.List>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group" style="display : inline-flex;">
            <label asp-for="Task" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Task" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Task" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item)
            </td>
            <td>

                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display : inline-flex;">
                <label class="control-label"></label>
                <input name="Send" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display : inline-flex;">
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo that you could refer to:

*Model:*

```
 public class TaskList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*Controller:*

```
    public IActionResult TaskList()
    {
        var model = _context.Tasks.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTask(string send)
    {
        var item = new TaskList ();
        item.Name = send;
        _context.Tasks.Add(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("TaskList");
    }
```

*TaskList view:*

```
@model ICollection<WebApplication1.Models.Tasks.TaskList>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>

                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="CreateTask">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group" style="display : inline-flex;">
            <label class="control-label"></label>
            <input name="Send" class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="display : inline-flex;">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Result:*

[image]